# Joomla: Can I auto assign country/language user group on registration?

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I'm developing a multi-lingual site for a client in Joomla 2.5. I wonder if there is any way to auto assign newly registered users to a group based on the language they are on when they register.

I.e. so if I visit the Italian site and register I will automatically be put in the group "Italian".

The underlying reason I want to this is to better separate the forum sections in my Kunena forum so that, for example, Italian users only have access to the Italian forum. Is there a way to solve this in a better way?

Also, I understand that this is by no means any kind of guarantee for people sticking to their respective language's forum but it is a request from the client who wants to direct the users as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the language information are stored inside a cookie, so you can't access them server-side.

You should create a user plugin: when the user register, you can try to guess the country using IP lookup, then add it to the linked user group.